# Phonegap geolocation in Blackberry

Tags: cordova, blackberry, geolocation

I am developing a phonegap based app in Blackberry. In this I am accessing current position's lattitude and longitude.If the Location Services is off, then how can I get to know ?. Can I set timeout for getting current location or any other ways?.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you can actually set both a maximum age and a timeout for the call

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(positionSuccess, positionError, { 
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        maximumAge: 9000,
        timeout: 10000                  
    });
```

in this case, the maximum age is set to 9 seconds and the timeout is set to 10 seconds

Comment: After 10 seconds what happens? Means can I give an alert saying location services is off?